# How to get nextElementSibling type via JS?

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid

I want to check if the nextElementSibling Element is present and if it is a  field. But I don't find the correct JS request.

```
document.getElementById($id).nextElementSibling.type
```

does not work.

Comment: You want type or tagname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nodeName, or tagName.

```js
var nextElement = document.getElementById('demo').nextElementSibling.nodeName;
console.log(nextElement);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<p>
hola
</p>
</div>
<p>
next element
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `quertSelector` and `+*` to get the next sibling

```js
let nextSibling = document.querySelector('#main+*')

if(!nextSibling){
  console.log("There is no next sibling")
}
else if(nextSibling.nodeName === "INPUT"){
  console.log("Next sibling is input field")
}
else {
  console.log("next sibling exists but its not input field")
}
console.log(nextSibling);
```

```html
<div><div id="main">This is my element</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="I am first sibling" />
<input type="text" placeholder="I am second sibling" />
</div>
<span></span>
```